# Can´t knit: Error in knn(..) : no missing values are allowed

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-markdown

When I try to knit my document the following error appears:

[image]

But I don´t seem to have any missing data and I can run perfectly the command manually:

```
 table(is.na(test))
  FALSE 
1122000 

table(is.na(train))
  FALSE 
2278000 

table(is.na(train_label))
FALSE 
 6700
```

```
 bin_test_pred_1 <- knn(train = train, test = test, cl =train_label, k = 1,
                        prob = TRUE)
```

Does anyone know where the issue migth be?

Thanks in advance,
Jose

Comment: Why are you sharing `table(is.na(train_label))`, while you used `train_labelbin` in your main code?

It'll be better if you share a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: sorry for the typo